# Using enum values in LinkedList

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to pass gender value to a LinkedList but it gives an error.

```
public class Employee{

    private String name;
    private String last;
    private Gender gender;
    private int ID;

    Employee(int ID, String name, String last, Gender gender){

        this.name=name;
        this.last=last;
        this.gender=gender;
        this.ID=ID;
    }

    public enum Gender {
        M,F
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Employee> oopClass = new LinkedList<>();

    oopClass.add(100,"Mick","tayson",M);
    oopClass.add(101,"Jonny","Tayson",F );
    oopClass.add(108,"Barack","Obama",F);
    oopClass.add(105,"Vlad","Putin",M);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add instances of Employee to the List :

```
oopClass.add(new Employee(100,"Mick","tayson",M));
oopClass.add(new Employee(101,"Jonny","Tayson",F));
oopClass.add(new Employee(108,"Barack","Obama",F));
oopClass.add(new Employee(105,"Vlad","Putin",M));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add instance of Employee to the linked list. So change

```
oopClass.add(100,"Mick","tayson",M);

oopClass.add(101,"Jonny","Tayson",F );

 oopClass.add(108,"Barack","Obama",F);

oopClass.add(105,"Vlad","Putin",M);
```

to

```
oopClass.add(new Employee(100,"Mick","tayson",M));

oopClass.add(new Employee(101,"Jonny","Tayson",F ));

oopClass.add(new Employee(108,"Barack","Obama",F));

oopClass.add(new Employee(105,"Vlad","Putin",M));
```